# Sublime ruby tests no output with Guard and Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sublimetext2, guard, spork

I have set up Guard and Spork along with Sublime ruby tests according to the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. However, when I run tests within sublime text with Ctrl+Shift+R/T/E I don't get any output except for "[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]", but if I check the terminal that Guard is running in I see all the output from Rspec.
What should I do to get the proper output shown in sublime text when I use Ruby Test?

Answer (score 1):

The output is displayed in terminal window running spork.

when a --drb option is specified the command is deligated to spork which runs the test and ouputs the results to the window(STDOUT).

ps: I was searching for a way to redirect the output back to sublime when I saw this question

Comment: If you find a way to redirect the output to sublime text, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work if you installed the sublime-text-2-ruby-tests:

https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests

See the screen shot on that page.  However it's now broken for me.  I opened a bug report here:

https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/issues/257